# XOFF проигнорирован, мр-бр-бр

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Скрин]

При Ctrl+S выскакивает вот это чудо. Как исправить, или как хотя бы сохранить файл?

Comment: А при запуске нано у вас внизу его экрана не показываются подсказки?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev При Ctrl + O та же проблема, если вы об этом.

Comment: Вот когда терминал при ^O выдаёт XOFF — тут я уже не знаю, что сказать. Чудеса...

Comment: А не надо Ctrl+S(приостановка вывода в терминал) нажимать)

Comment: А нет, при Ctrl + O работает. Странно ибо на локалке у меня тот же дистрибутив, и этой ошибки нету.

Comment: Зашёл в вопрос только из-за названия. Надо же, прямо так и звучит как [XOFF ignored, mumble mumble](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71053/176784), вот же кто-то подобрал сообщение об ошибке. Даже немного жаль, что никогда не видел сам, ибо я пользуюсь той самой программой из которой не все могут выйти.

Comment: @AK Я как раз использую nano, потому что когда надо просто чего-то там отредактировать или небольшой тестктовый файл, то удобно. А vim — это конечно да ;)

Comment: Т.е. vim для небольших правок - неудобно? Отчего же? [Пищит и всё портит](https://bash.im/quote/401)? =)

Comment: @vp_arth ага ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> - (XOFF) команда терминалу приостановить вывод
<kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> - (XON) возобновить вывод

nano перехватывает эти комбинации с вот таким уведомлением, чтобы пользователь, случайно нажавший <kbd>^S</kbd>, мог работать дальше.

---

Если вам всё же нужны эти команды:

`man nano`

> ```
> -p, --preserve
>   Preserve the XON and XOFF sequences (^Q and ^S) so they will be caught by the terminal.
> ```

Сохранение в nano работает по <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> или (с вопросом перед выходом) <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd>

---

Впрочем, начиная с версии [2.9.0 "Eta" (18.11.2017г)](https://www.nano-editor.org/news.php), nano по умолчанию использует эти хоткеи иначе:

> makes ^Q and ^S do something useful by default
> (^Q starts a backward search, and ^S saves the current file)

<kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> - Сохранить текущий файл
<kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> - Поиск назад